# Fire onKeyPress Event passing parameters using JQuery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using Chrome to test one of the MVC view in my application where I have two arrow links on the page and I want to execute certain functions by passing parameters when user presses left/right arrow key.

Here is my markup and scripts.

```html
@if (ViewBag.PreviousId != null)
        {
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" id="btnPrevious" 
               onclick="GetImage('@ViewBag.PreviousId','lArrow')" onkeypress="KeyboardClick(event,'@ViewBag.PreviousId')">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
        }
        @if (ViewBag.NextId != null)
        {
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" id="btnNext" 
               onclick="GetImage('@ViewBag.NextId','rArrow')" onkeypress="return KeyboardClick(event,'@ViewBag.PreviousId')">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        }
```

```
function KeyboardClick(e, id) {
//Check if it is left/right arrow key
if (e.which == 37) {
    GetImage(id, 'lArrow');
} else if (e.which == 39) {
    GetImage(id, 'rArrow');
}
```

}

The above code does not work when I press the arrow keys on Keyboard. I want the onKeyPress to work similar to onClick().

I have found a lot of examples/answers that explain how to associate the event to any DOM element or fire it, But none of them explain how I can pass the parameters. Please advise how this can be solved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use `document.onkeypress = function (e) { ... };`. (your arrow links will never receive those keyboard events)

Comment: But here my need is to pass the parameter to that event. If I add it this way, how do I pass the Id?

Comment: Do you though? Isn't the id simply `'@ViewBag.PreviousId'`? Why do you need to pass it? And from where? Can you show the `GetImage` function please? (btw, there's exactly zero jQuery in your code)

Comment: @viewbag.PreviousId is a dynamic value that keeps changing everytime the page is loaded, my script has no access to use it directly. I would have to pass it as a parameter only to any javascript/jquery function from the html markup/page.

Comment: Ok, so add it like this: `<a class="left carousel-control" data-prev="@ViewBag.PreviousId">`. Then do `$('btnPrevious').data('prev')` to grab it from the left arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that keypress events aren't sent to specific elements (unless it's like an `<input>` currently in focus) but only to `window` and `document`. So that's where the event handler needs to be attached.

Next, the server-side information about the previous and next ID has to be readily available to the script, one simple way is to put it in a `data` attribute of a relevant element. I'm using the two slider arrows here.

The final piece is more a recommendation: to avoid duplicate code, both clicking an arrow and pressing an arrow key should cause the same handler function to run. One way to do this is to simply call `click()` on the respective arrow element if a key is pressed:

```js
function GetImage(id, arrow) {
  console.log(id, arrow)
}

$(function() {

  const $leftArrow = $('#btnPrevious');
  const $rightArrow = $('#btnNext');

  $leftArrow.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    GetImage($(this).data('id'), 'lArrow');
  });

  $rightArrow.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    GetImage($(this).data('id'), 'rArrow');
  });

  $(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    const ev = e.originalEvent;
    if (ev.keyCode === 37) $leftArrow.click();
    if (ev.keyCode === 39) $rightArrow.click();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<a class="left carousel-control" href="" data-slide="prev" id="btnPrevious" data-id="@ViewBag.PreviousId">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="" data-slide="next" id="btnNext" data-id="@ViewBag.NextId">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

(When you run the snippet, click in the output area first to catch key presses)